# $E_1\oplus E_2\neq\mathbb{R}^3$ proof exercise

Tags: linear-algebra

For each of the following pairs $E_1,E_2$ of a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, determine $E_1+E_2$ and prove if $E_1\oplus E_2=\mathbb{R}^3$:

$E_1=\{(a,a,a):a\in\mathbb{R}\};E_2=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x+y+z=0\}$

$E_1\bigcap E_2=0$, once z=-x-y so that $E_2=(x,y,-x-y)$, so the intersersection is (a,a,a)=(x,y,-x-y).

I know $x+y+z=0$ stands for a plain but $(a,a,a)$ is a point in which all coordinates are $a$ so the sum of $E_1\oplus E_2\neq\mathbb{R}^3$.

However I cannot prove this in a more formal and complete way.

**Questions**:

Could someone provide me a more complete and formal proof?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The direct sum is indeed $\mathbb{R}^3$. An easy way to see this is that they have trivial intersection and dimension sum 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$e_2=(1,-1,0)$ and $e_3=(0,1,-1)$ are independant and $(e_2,e_3)$ is a base of $E_2$

$e_1=(1,1,1)$ is a base of $E_1$

Since $e_1.e_2=0$ and $e_1.e_3=0$ you get $E_1=E_2^\perp$ and finally $E_1 \bigoplus E_2=\mathbb{R}^3$

Answer (score 1):

dim($E_1$)+dim($E_1$)-dim($E_1\cap E_2$)=dim($E_1\oplus E_2$)
$E_1$ is of dimension 1(basis (1,1,1)). $E_2$ is a of dimension 2(basis (1,0,-1) and (0,1,-1)) and their intersection has a dimension 0
Therefore dimension of $E_1\oplus E_2$ is 3 and is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$
Hence $E_1\oplus E_2=\mathbb{R}^3$
the mistake you made was that (a,a,a) was not a point but a line

Comment: The basis of $E_2$ could also be (-1,1,0) and (-1,0,1), right?

Comment: YES, the condition is symmetric and just exchange the roles of $x$ and $z$ and you get the one that I gave. I wrote z=-x-y and you wrote x=-y-z.